# How do I check to see if data exists in a particular field of my model in backbone?

Tags: backbone.js, tastypie

I have a model.
I have notes that I add to that model.
No problems there.

When I instantiate the view, I want to see if the data.objects has content in the note.

Where do I put the if statement? In the view render? And how do I test for it.

js and backbone noob here, so please forgive me missing the basics.

Lemme know and many thanks.

Any references to tutorials are welcome.

UPDATE: Here's the View for my model

```
var BlasterView = Backbone.View.extend({

    tagName: 'li',
    className: 'blaster',

    events: {

        'click .td-blaster a': 'done'

    },

    initialize: function() {

        _.bindAll(this, 'render');

    },

    render: function(){

        this.$el.html(ich.blasterTemplate(this.model.toJSON()));
        return this;

    },

    done: function(){

        this.model.toggle();

        this.$el.animate({
            backgroundColor:'#faeca9'
        }, 600 ).delay(600).fadeOut('fast');

        return false;

    }

});
```

Comment: It's a bit difficult to see what it being asked here? What has this got to do with backbone or tastypie? What code have you put together yourself. Show use your models and your view at the moment

Comment: Of course, sorry about that. I added the view. Please let me know if it'd make sense to add more.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
render: function(){

    if( this.model.get('particularField') ){
       console.log('Particular Field has a value');
    }else{
       console.log('Particular Field does NOT have a value');
    }

    this.$el.html(ich.blasterTemplate(this.model.toJSON()));
    return this;

},
```

If you mean that also the field is an instance of an object, just do this, check that particularField is not empty and also check that the nested property is set:

```
if( this.model.get('particularField') && 
this.model.get('particularField').someChildAttr){
```

**UPDATE:**

"Backbone now supports the has property" (via: @TyroneMichael). So you can just use:

```
this.model.has('particularField')
```

Comment: Awesomeness! I'll check this out today and report back. Thanks for your time!

Comment: Backbone now supports the has property. So you can just use this.model.has('particularField').